# Javascript: How to sort a sequence of elements in an array by two values?

Tags: javascript

i have unsorted array

```
[
    {val: 'one', vale: 'two'},
    {val: 'three', vale: 'four'},
    {val: 'two', vale: 'three'},
    {val: 'six', vale: 'one'}

]
```

How to sort to get such a sequence, like vale === next val

```
[
    {val: 'one', vale: 'two'},
    {val: 'two', vale: 'three'},
    {val: 'three', vale: 'four'},
    {val: 'five', vale: 'six'},
    {val: 'six', vale: 'one'}
]
```

Comment: What are you sorting the elements by? It seems you are trying to sort by numerical value but you only have the string values present.

Comment: If you have 'six' pointing to 'one' no algorithm can guarantee that 'one' will be the first element unless it understands the semantic meaning of 'one' somehow.

Comment: @Lix its just exmaple, Instead of a line with numbers there can be any value that must be equal to the following property val

Comment: @Drop: If it can be any pairs of values, then how do you know which one should be first in the list? It makes sense with words that represent numbers, but not so much with words that don't suggest a starting point. If there's no definite starting point, then it should be pretty simple.

Comment: @llama yea, i think about it, first object will always be the start, and it starts sorting

Comment: i think tru use reduce or sort , but something is completely confused

Comment: in reallity you would get `five -> six -> one -> two -> three -> four`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop the array and use a nested loop starting at the index after the outer loop to find the next item by comparing the outer loop's `vale` to the inner loop's `val`.

When a match is found, swap the members (unless it's already in place), and break the inner loop to continue with the outer.

```js
var data = [
    {val: 'one', vale: 'two'},
    {val: 'three', vale: 'four'},
    {val: 'two', vale: 'three'},
    {val: 'six', vale: 'one'},
    {val: 'four', vale: 'five'},
    {val: 'five', vale: 'six'}
];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
  for (var j = i+1; j < data.length; j++) {
    if (data[i].vale === data[j].val) {
      if (i+1 !== j) {
        [data[i+1], data[j]] = [data[j], data[i+1]]; // Swap the members.
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

At first resolve all *vales* by looking them up:

```
input.forEach( obj => {
  obj.to = input.find( el => el.val === obj.vale );
  if(obj.to) obj.to.from = obj;
});
```

So now we've got a chain we can resolve easily:

```
const result = [];
var current = input.find(obj => !obj.from) // the first in chain
do {
  result.push( current );
} while( current = current.to );
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##XZDBboMwDIbveQqvF0Dt0nsRu@0pph1ScEaqLEYh0EoVz86cQFW6nBz5@3//9kWNqq@96cK7owbnuSbXBzCuGwJU8CWA331U9gQZOcwOwDXyJ1wpmw7bdmg9bgBNg/9PsOZpkPBXoDe3JxDHTUJ8l0KkOFKT/1R1mwOdL1B9wJ2lXMpAnHRFjGtyQBvbaCU7QVVViYquUJSsMTpfZMUql9rTLySsFBMzYrmCx36w6QwcYlQe6sF7dOF13JrmLXpFowKORwgtgjY@nRLqVhknGkqJF1PZDT1vshrGcPvdabff/FPYCa6tsZhvJj8Q3vqRlCxKSz/5Yl2U8/wH)

Comment: Hope you realize this algorithm is O(N^2)

Comment: No, you tried to do the other student's homework, but failed

Comment: @george whats wrong with you? 1) why do you think its an homework? 2) why shouldn't i help then ? 3) why did i fail ?

Comment: 3) Probably you skipped the lecture about algorithmic complexities. I consider an increased algorithmic complexity a failure, especially that a better complexity can be achieved without any effort. Can you tell what is the algorithmic complexity of the find method, which you are using in a loop? Consequently, what is the complexity of the entire algorithm? What happens when you your problem scales to 10000 items?

Comment: @george still: Whats Your Problem?? 1) This is javascript. It will never run that fast. 2) why should i care? It will run smooth for a few 1000 items, i dont see any need to invest time into optimizing it. 3) why don't you add your own answer then ( if you're that clever ), 4) and that has nothing todo with my education?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158024/discussion-between-george-polevoy-and-jonas-w).

Answer (score -2):

The operation you described is not a sorting operation. It's a linked list traversal. First convert your array to a map, then use the linked list traversal algorithm and adapt it. Instead of a 'next' property of the nodes, you would use the second property of your items as the key in the map.

You need to explicitly specify the starting node, because your key space is not ordered.

The algorithm below uses an additional map of visited keys, because your linked list has a cycle.

The algorithm scales linearly by the number of items:

```js
const N = 10000;

const input = [];

for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
 input.push({val : i.toString(), vale : (i+1).toString()});
}
input[N-1].vale = 0; // cycle

var start = input[0];

// Shuffle the array
for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  var a = Math.floor(Math.random() * N);
  var b = Math.floor(Math.random() * N);
 [input[a], input[b]] = [input[b], input[a]];
}

var t0 = performance.now();

// Prepare the map
const m = {};
for (var i in input) {
 var o = input[i];
  m[o.val] = o;
}
const result = [];
var current = start;
const visited = {}; // This map guards from infinite loop, if there is a cycle.
while (true) {
 if (visited[current.val]) {
   break;
  }
  visited[current.val] = true;
 result.push(current);
  current = m[current.vale];
}

var t1 = performance.now();

console.log("Elapsed " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")

console.log(result.slice(1, 10));
console.log(result.slice(N - 10, N));
```

Comment: Yes, I tried to do something like this through reduce, but used it not quite as needed and got in the previous value undefined

Comment: I just wondered, if this algorithm would be faster than two for cycles.
I just dont work with hashmap

Comment: Yes, it would. Hash map is O(1), and a cycle is O(N).

Comment: But how i understand, if in objects be more properties, we will lose all other properties when we convert array to hashmap

Comment: No, you've got all of the original objects intact in the resulting array. The references are being added as hash map values, this operation does not modify the objects themselves.